# Django Tutorial Page Not Found

Tags: python, django

I have been following along with the Django tutorial for the poll app. I keep getting a 404 error when heading to the site. I have checked quite a few questions for this problem but I wasn't able to find a solution

[here is the screenshot of the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faUzs.png)

```
   '''
    Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    
    
    ^polls/
    ^admin/
    The empty path didn’t match any of these.
    '''
```

my code is as follows

mysite\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
               ]
```

views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Comment: replace this `'^$'` with this: `''`

Comment: What URL are you trying, and what do you expect to happen as a result?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the index view in polls\views.py - it should say "Hello, world. You're at the polls index."

Comment: @Alireza yeah still getting the same 404 error

Comment: Could you copy the error, so we can see the full message. This might be helpful

Comment: @tim-mccurrach i updated the post to show the ss of the error

Comment: In your own words, how do you think the `urlpatterns` work? What does the tutorial say about how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to not get the error:

As things are set up at the moment you would need to navigate to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls
```

#### Why does it work this way

Your `ROOT_URLCONF` is currently set to `mysite.url.py` (as it should be). This means that this is where django looks to resolve your request. It looks through each path in turn. If it matches `polls`, it will then look at all the urls in `include('polls.urls')`, but it needs to match that first polls bit before looking further.

#### How can I fix it?

One thing you could do is this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

That way, django will look at `polls.urls` regardless.